# Encoding UIImage to Base64 string not working when transferred to server

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

Encoding an UIImage as a Base64 string works on the device, but transferring the string to the server somehow corrupts the string and prevents the server from successfully decoding the image.

Any suggestions on the problem?

```
        // Define params
        params["thumbnail_base64"] = imageToBase64(blockSet.thumbnailURL)
        ...

        // Convert params -> query string
        let postString = buildQueryString(params)

        // Define upload URL
        let uploadURL = NSURL(string: RootURL + UploadFilePath)!

        // Hit server
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: uploadURL)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        ...

private func buildQueryString(parameters: [String:String], omitQuestionMark: Bool = false) -> String {
    var urlVars = [String]()
    for (k, var v) in parameters {
        v = v.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
        urlVars += [k + "=" + "\(v)"]
    }
    return ((urlVars.isEmpty || omitQuestionMark) ? "" : "?") + urlVars.joinWithSeparator("&")
}


private func imageToBase64(filename: String) -> String {
    // Get image path
    let imagePath = getFilePath(filename)

    // Convert image to base64 or return empty string
    if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: imagePath) {
        let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed)
        return base64String
    } else {
        printError("Error converting image to Base64: missing image. Filename: \(filename)")
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check server side data type where you stored base64 string. make sure it'll be Long Text datatype.

Comment: when encocoding use `base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)` and decoding `NSData(base64EncodedString: imageBase64EncodedString, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters)`

Comment: The problem it is probably with your json string data. Don't hard code your JSON data. Create a dictionary and serialize it using NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: [])

Comment: @LeoDabus could you elaborate and post as an answer please? What do you mean hard code your JSON data?

Comment: @LeoDabus why Encoding64CharacterLineLength vs EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed? Another SO answer used EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed, and that part seems to work fine (e.g., the Base64 produced from Swift can get decoded back to an image when testing with online Base64 decoders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `queryString`, base64 is long text with many characters, let `JSON` do the work for you

Use the next (with some example of NodeJS)

```
  let params = NSMutableDictionary();
  //you can only set `serializable` values
  params.setValue(imageToBase64(),forKey:"base64")
  params.setValue(username,forKey:"username")
  params.setValue(["array","of","string"],forKey:"arr")

  let uploadURL = NSURL(string: theURL)!

  // Hit server
  let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: uploadURL)
  request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

  request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

  do {
      let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0))
      request.HTTPBody = jsonData
      let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

      session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
          print("Response: \(response)")
      }).resume()


  } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error)
  }
```

nodejs:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(request.body["base64"], 'base64')
fs.writeFile('test.jpeg',buffer,"base64"); //Works
var username = request.body["username"];
var someStringsArr  = request.body["arr"]
```

*by the way...*

you wrote the function `buildQueryString`, which is already exists in `Foundation`

```
let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: "http://myUrl.com/getApi/")!
urlComponents.queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem]()
urlComponents.queryItems!.append(NSURLQueryItem(name:"myKeyA",value:"myValueA"))
urlComponents.queryItems!.append(NSURLQueryItem(name:"myKeyB",value:"myValueB"))

print(urlComponents.URL!) //http://myUrl.com/getApi/?myKeyA=myValueA&myKeyB=myValueB
```

Use url query if want to send `GET` parameters via the `URL`

Comment: what if you have multiple parameters and need to pass them in the POST request? for instance, let's say you need to pass in username and userID as well as the base64 string.

Comment: ok thanks, but how come on the server you didn't have to decode the JSON -encoded parameters?

Comment: @Crashalot using nodeJS library called `body-parser`.


`var app = express()
.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '200mb'})) //for application/json
.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true,limit: '200mb'})) //for urlquery`. the library injects the decoded JSON to the request object

Comment: + because of the `application/json` header, some languages will auto decode the data for use, for example PHP you can get the `post` values with the global `$_POST["base64"]` object

Comment: it seems ruby/rails also supports JSON auto-decoding. thanks so much for your help! :)