# How to remove WhiteSpace between base64 string in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, base64

I referred to  [remove whitespaces from base64 encoded string when posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032233/remove-whitespaces-from-base64-encoded-string-when-posting) but still I have this problem

I am currently using the following code :

```
NSString *TrimBase64String=[base64String stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: maybe you can display a sample data?

Comment: MyString=cdkajcfkncjfkheohfnjdenjcvnbjdncvjfdkjashnfdncldknvfkrlvnklrnvslkdvnfdlskv   APIstring=cdkajcfkncjfkheohfnjdenjcvnb jdncvjfdkja shnfdncldknvfkrlvn  klrnvslkdvn  fdlskv

Comment: @MacBoy - Can you elaborate your problem a bit more ? Do you want to remove all white spaces or only the more than ones

Comment: All white space @gagansharma

Comment: @MacBoy - I tested stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString is removing all white-spaces, for further investigation please share your code snippets or exact string  you are modifying...

Comment: Removed unnecessary words

Answer (score 0):

Easy Peasy, use this line:

```
NSString *TrimBase64String=[base64String stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: This should remove the white space characters that are at the begining or at the end only, not the one in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Use below lines of code to create `NSString` with Base64 Encoding to avoid white spaces and then post it:

```
NSString *strbase64 = [YourNSData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
```

Check answer here, may be it will help more:

[encode image to base64, get a invalid base64 string (ios using base64EncodedStringWithOptions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243854/encode-image-to-base64-get-a-invalid-base64-string-ios-using-base64encodedstri)

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways and finally found the cause of the problem is the character `\r`

> \r = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character in Mac OS before X`

`[yourBase64String stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];`